# Ubuntu 18.10 suddenly stopped recognizing headphone jack

Tags: sound, headphones, 18.10

Suddenly Ubuntu stopped recognizing the headphone jack on my ThinkPad E480. It worked fine before, and it works fine when I boot into Windows. Only thing that I changed in the system is that I installed Okular.

Plugging any audio device into the jack does nothing. Speakers still work. Pavucontrol shows only "Speakers" in the ports menu, no headphone jack.

Tried `alsactl restore` to no avail.

Card: HDA Intel PCH, Chip: Conexant CX20753/4

Edit: The issue started happening when I was on Ubuntu 19.04. I have since made a clean install of Ubuntu 18.10 and the problem persists.